# В чем различия OpenFeign и Kafka?

Tags: архитектура, микросервисы, apache-kafka

[image: Взаимодействие микросервисов]

Руководитель требует разделить данную связь между мкиросервисами на FeignClient и на kafka.

В каких случаях лучше использовать FeignClient для взаимодействия между микросервисами, а когда Kafka?